# AspNetCore 2.1 web api передача xml в теле Post запроса

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Здравствуйте нужно передать вот такой такой XML документ

```
<tlist>
    <t>
        <ScheduleId>12254</ScheduleId>
        ...
    </t>
    <t>
        <ScheduleId>333333</ScheduleId>
        ...
    </t>
</tlist>
```

Добавил поддержку `"application/xml" services.AddXmlSerializerFormatters()`

```
[HttpPost]
[Produces("application/xml")]
public void Post([FromBody] ТипДляПриемаDto trainsList)
{

}
```

Создал тип TrainDto и вернул List через GET запрос, получилось так:

```
public class TrainDto
{
   public int  ScheduleId { get; set; }
}

<ArrayOfTrainDto xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <TrainDto>
        <ScheduleId>0</ScheduleId>
    </TrainDto>
</ArrayOfTrainDto>
```

То есть коллекция объектов оборачивается в тег `<ArrayOf...>` в обработчике по умолчанию.

Подскажите как написать свой обработчик XML или придется принимать XML как строку и самому парсить?

Comment: Тогда не будет работать атрибут [Produces("application/xml")] а без него не происходит автоматические Binding и Mapping из данных в теле запроса в тип Dto.  Я так понял по умолчанию поддерживается только "application/json" и даже просто строку в POST запросе не передать с 
ContentType= "text/plain"

Comment: Неплохо бы дописать в вопрос как вы передаёте документ в веб-приложение, как вы его сериализуете.

Comment: @AK но зачем, если сам запрос уже приведен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayOfTrainDto у вас вышло исключительно потому что это корневой элемент, и для него неоткуда взять имя кроме как из типа данных. Если вам нужно особое имя - вам нужен особый тип данных.

XML Serializer можно настраивать с помощью атрибутов:

```
[XmlRoot("tlist")]
public class TrainsDtoContainer
{
    [XmlElement("t")]
    public List<TrainDto> Trains { get; set; } = new List<TrainDto>();
}
```

Замечу, что отдельный тип-контейнер нужен только для ситуации "массив в корне". Для массивов в других местах контейнер можно создать через XmlArrayAttribute (еще он будет создан по умолчанию если вообще не использовать атрибутов):

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class SomeAnotherDto
{
    [XmlArray("tlist"), XmlArrayItem("t")]
    public List<TrainDto> Trains { get; set; } = new List<TrainDto>();
}
```

Но, вообще говоря, сложные xml-документы обычно описываются при помощи xsd-схемы. По такой схеме можно автоматически получить все нужные классы с помощью [xsd.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe)

Comment: Спасибо, не догадался что обычные XML атрибуты (System.Xml.Serialization) тут тоже работают.